# How do I remove stick-on tile residue from a plywood subfloor?

Tags: flooring

I pulled up old stick on tile from a plywood subfloor which is now so sticky it pulls my shoes off.  I need to get this surface ready to install vinyl planking which needs to be able to "float" on the surface. This is a small poorly-ventilated room, so chemicals are out.  I see some have tried corn starch or baking soda.....any helpful input for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dusted the subfloor with corn starch and swept it around...instant non-sticky surface that stayed absolutely non-sticky to lay my vinyl plank flooring.  There can't be any easier solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

The sticky residue shouldn't be an issue once you have laid your underlayment. After that point the installation process will have the desired floating affect.

Side note: The sticky subfloor might actually aid in keeping the underlayment in place while your vinyl flooring is installed.

Comment: Thanks, but the vinyl plank I am installing not only doesn't require underlayment, it specifically prohibits using any.  It has a layer of "underlayment" built into the planks.  I did end up dusting the sticky surface with corn starch and sweeping it in with a soft broom....it worked like a miracle.

Answer (score 1):

I would "wallpaper" the floor with red rosin paper AKA builder's paper. It's commonly available in rolls 36" wide by 166 feet long for less than $20 in big box home improvement stores. Since the floor is so sticky, there's no need to apply any adhesive.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, I actually thought about doing it. But, I did try dusting with corn starch and that worked incredibly well....the surface was completely 'sticky free' after I did that.

Comment: @PapaDon Please post that as an _answer_, then click the check mark next to your answer as soon as the system will allow it. That way others will be able to find your excellent solution. (So long as the corn starch doesn't rot and smell...)

Comment: I used red rosin paper on my 'sticky' floor.   It works, it's cheap and it's easy.  Note, corn starch properties could diminish over time..weight on the floor could push through the particles and into the adhesive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've ruled out chemicals, which probably would not have worked as well as you need anyway, I suspect you will find that the only solution is to either REMOVE the subfloor that is covered with glue and replace it, or ADD a layer of floor underlayment (i.e. Lauan) and cover up the messy subfloor.

Comment: Yes, I considered that too.  I decided to try dusting with corn starch since I had some in the pantry and a failure wouldn't cost anything...it worked like a miracl.  Dusted and swept around, the surface was smooth and the vinyl planks were able to float freely.  Thanks for your input, it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Benzyl alcohol.

"Klean-Strip Green Floor Adhesive Remover removes adhesives from wood, concrete, metal and masonry. It's easy to use because it stays wet and active for up to 24 hours. Low odor and less harsh on skin. **No methylene chloride**. Keep out of reach of children." https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klean-Strip-Green-1-Gal-Floor-Adhesive-Remover-GKGF75015/206804537

[image]

**Eye and skin irritant.** A poorly-ventilated room isn't really a problem. Just don't get it on your skin. I just went through ten gallons of this for ~1000 sq ft, and while I never want to smell it again, it wasn't that bad, and without it the carpet adhesive wouldn't have come up.

You cover it in plastic sheeting and come back, *in less than 24 hours*, but not less than 8, and it sloughs right off. You put the spoils outside in the sun to dry, and then they can just be thrown away.

Comment: Good luck finding any, I just bought it all from three different stores ;)